# Openshift HaProxy gear shuts down

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openshift, haproxy, openshift-cartridge

I have a spring boot web application that uses
WildFly Application Server 10,
Mysql server

The problem is that it randomly shuts down. Every few days. Currently it is scaled from 1 small gear to 16
[image]